# trouble loading a simple hello world on django 2.1

Tags: django

I'm entirely new to Django. Here I'm trying to create my first project following every detailed step mentioned in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/).

But yet I face this error by entering http://localhost:8000/polls/ :

```
 using the urlconf defined in mysite.urls, django
 tried these url patterns, in this order:
    1. admin/
```

I was wondering if any of you guys ever encountered the same or have something to say about it. Thanks.

Comment: You probably forgot to edit `mysite/urls.py` (adding `polls/`) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view

Comment: I've done this completely as the tutorial has instructed but yet I get the same error

Comment: Thank you it worked when I went through building up my project from zero.